# Run javascript on btn but not container

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got this:
http://jsfiddle.net/G3VjC/

which is simply:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(document).on('click','#btn',function(){
    console.log('ran btn');
});
$(document).on('click','#containerdiv',function(){
    console.log('ran div');
});
```

});

But when clicking the button is run the btn JS and the container JS (see console log).

How can I separate them?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `stopPropagation()`

```
$(document).on('click','.meee',function(e){ // add event as argument
    console.log('ran btn');
    e.stopPropagation()
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click','#containerdiv',function(){
        console.log('ran div');

    });

    $(document).on('click','.meee',function(){
        console.log('ran btn');
        return false;
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/G3VjC/2/)

Comment: returning false is not always the best option, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false

Answer (score 0):

Or try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#containerdiv').click(function(){
        console.log('ran div');
    });

   $('.meee').click(function(e){
           e.stopPropagation();
           console.log('ran btn');
   });
});
```

As chumkiu already said, just use stopPropagation()

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click','#btn',function(e){
e.stoppropagation();
var target = $(e.target);
if(!target.attr('id') == 'btn'){
 e.preventDefault();
 $(target.find("#btn)).trigger("click")
}
//any additional logic if the target was of the intended type.
});
```